# delete items at the same position (index) from two synchronized lists?

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
l1 = ['#', '1', '#', '!']
l2 = ['S', 'T', 'K', 'M']
```

If there is a '#' in l1 I want to remove it, and remove whatever is at the same position in l2. 
This is what I have tried (among several other things):

```
for i in range(len(li[j])):
    for k in range(len(l2[n])):
        if j == "#":
            li.remove([j][i])
            l2.remove([n][k])
```

But it complains that j is not defined. 
I want the outcome to look like this:

```
l1 = ['1', '!']
l2 = ['T', 'M']
```

I would be grateful for suggestions!

Comment: Where do you set `j`? And to what?

Comment: `li.remove` it should be `l1`, and your loop variables are `i`, `k` there is no `j`, hence `j` is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple and easy to understand method:

```
a = ["#", "1", "#", "2", "3", "#"]
b = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

a,b = zip(*[[a[i], b[i]] for i in range(len(a)) if a[i]!="#"])
print a
print b
```

Personally I find it much simplier to understand and more effective (read: "faster") than the method @jamylak proposed.

Output:

```
>>> 
('1', '2', '3')
('b', 'd', 'e')
```

Comment: I wouldn't say this is simpler to understand than my method. You make repeated calls to each variable used whereas my method makes use of inbuilt methods so each variable only has to be used once. The names, eg. filter seem to make the method clear to anybody with experience with python.

Comment: @jamylak I'm a newbie in python, seemed to me that zipping it twice would take more processing power than using a simple generator. Now it seems I could be wrong, as inbuilt functions are faster than a piece of python code.

Comment: Of course, although python is not always about speed. Sometimes I sacrifice speed for readability just so the code looks better. If I used all the methods from itertools i could turn the zips into generators and that would run much faster although it would involve turning the data into a list again which is not worth posting for this example.

Comment: @jamylak Ok, now your new generator from a zip method you've added you your original answer is the one I like the most (from readability point of view). Anyway, learning something new every day :)

Comment: You mean the compress one? I think that is probably the best, itertools is always good :D

Comment: @jamylak No, actually this one: `zip(*((x,y) for x,y in zip(l1,l2) if x!='#'))`. But well, I guess it looks the prettiest to me because I'm new to python constructs at all, and this one is easiest for me to parse with my eyes :D

Comment: Oh right, yeah, I didn't think of adding that in at the start but nobody mentioned it. I think it is the most basic although I like the filter one more. I think it's more pythonic as i mentioned in a previous post... in-built functions look better to me.

Comment: @bezmax what if list a have sublist inside it. For example if a(would look like) = [["#",1],[1,34],["#",3],[2,6],["#",8]]. And then remove sublist if it has "#".

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> l1 = ['#', '1', '#', '!']
>>> l2 = ['S', 'T', 'K', 'M']

>>> l1,l2 = zip(*((x,y) for x,y in zip(l1,l2) if x!='#'))
>>> l1
('1', '!')
>>> l2
('T', 'M')
```

Using `filter`

```
>>> l1,l2 = zip(*filter(lambda x: '#' not in x,zip(l1,l2)))
>>> l1
('1', '!')
>>> l2
('T', 'M')
```

Using `itertools`

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> l1,l2 = zip(*compress(zip(l1,l2),(x!='#' for x in l1)))
>>> l1
('1', '!')
>>> l2
('T', 'M')
```

Answer (score 0):

As you always access the same index in both lists one loop is enough, however you need to be careful when the lists are not of the same length.

Moreover removing from a list while iterating over it is error-prone, the following solution stores all indices in a removal-list and will remove the index from both lists in a second go:

```
l1 = ['#', '1', '#', '!']    
l2 = ['S', 'T', 'K', 'M']
remove = []
for i in range(len(l1) - 1):
    if l1[i] == '#':
        remove.insert(0, i)

for i in remove:
    l1.pop(i)
    l2.pop(i)

for i in l1:
    print i
for i in l2:
    print i
```